# Is there a way to show ALL the compiler warnings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm cleaning up a project to get rid of all the warnings, but I can only see the first 100 or so in the Error List pane.

This is a problem because we're using Team Server for source control and all the warnings shown are in files that are currently checked out (and therefore I can't modify without making someone else possibly do a *lot* of work when they check in).

I'd like to be able to see the full list so I can continue my cleaning while others are working.

---

In case it makes a difference,

- The project in question is a VB.NET web application (using the application model). It doesn't seem that I can compile individual pages.
- Environment is VS2010 Premium; I can get Ultimate on my machine if necessary.

Comment: Why don't you make the people who have files checked out fix the warnings in these files?

Comment: @Andreas: I plan to: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206286/how-do-you-tell-someone-theyre-writing-bad-code) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512222/is-it-a-good-idea-to-eliminate-compiler-warnings). The issue is that there is work needing to be done by the others, and the sheer volume of fixes needed is quite large.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The full list of warnings should be visible in the output window.  After building open the output window, switch it to the build output and you should have access to all errors emitted by the compiler.

Note: The compiler itself still has a hard limit on the number of errors it will report for a given project (true for both VB and C#).  This cannot be overridden in Visual Studio or the command line.

Comment: The Output pane says "vbc : warning BC42206: Maximum number of warnings has been exceeded." and shows the same as the Error list. Regardless, if the compiler has a hard limit at ~100, then I guess I'm kinda stuck?

Comment: @Jon, unfortunately yes.  This number is hard coded into the compiler and cannot be overridden by even hacky means.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you temporarily locally do something similar to

```
#pragma warning disable
```

in the files which are checked out by the others so you don't have to see their warnings?

Comment: Hmmmm... I suppose I could. On check-in, I'd have to go back and figure out which files are the ones I *shouldn't* check in. This doesn't really answer my original question, but +1 because it's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order for me to get the full list of warnings to appear in Visual Studio 2022, I had to use the Menu Bar at the top of the screen, clicking on: `Analyse -> Run Code Analysis -> On Solution.`

Without doing this, the warnings would only appear for the files that I had open in Visual Studio, rather than all warnings appearing for the whole solution.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for files that are not open in the Editor.