# How can I find total number of warnings in project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, warnings

I've just converted a project from .net 1.1 to 3.5, and I'm being given loads of warnings in the error list.

The program compiles and runs ok, but I think I should probably try to at least reduce this large number of warnings.

The trouble is that the error list only tells me about the first 102 warnings. Even when I fix one, the number stays at 102. So I have absolutely no idea how many warnings there actually are.

If there are 150, I'd like to get rid of them. But if there are 10,000, I don't have the time to fix them all.

Is there a way to see the actual total number of warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this information relates to the error messages, I think it holds true for the warnings also. The answer seems to be: **NO**.

It was "no" in [2006](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/170749/wc-8-11-maximum-error-list) and it is still true for VS 2010:

[Provide configurable maximum error messages limit for VB.Net compiler](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613412/provide-configurable-maximum-error-messages-limit-for-vb-net-compiler)

> Thanks for the feedback on this issue. We agree that this is something that we would like to improve as we get this feedback a lot from customers who are upgrading their projects or trying to configure them on a new machine. We actually performed some experiments where we did this but it made the performance of the IDE too slow because of the overhead of tracking all of the errors. I'm resolving this issue as "Won't Fix" for now but we will likely revisit this in a future version of Visual Studio.

Comment: "No" in 2006. "No" in 2010. Way to evolve, Microsoft!

Answer (score 2):

Was already answered here on the board:

[Is there a way to show ALL the compiler warnings in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514491/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-the-compiler-warnings-in-visual-studio-2010)

I had the same Problem.. i can only suggest to outcomment large blocks and enable them step by step. So you have a quick overview on the real number of Warnings