# How to find specific implicit conversion in VS2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, implicit-conversion

I'm working on a big vb.net project on Visual Studio 2013 and I noticed this bug: `OverflowException` due to implicit conversion from `IntPtr` to `Integer` on a 64-bit platform.
I corrected this one but now I was looking for others possibly errors due to this kind of implicit conversion, how can I find them? <s>Or mark as error?</s> **Or check with a code analysis tool?**
Compiler [warnings](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a28ded13-e0e5-49a2-a962-65aeb001ee32/maximum-number-of-warnings-has-been-exceeded?forum=vbide) and [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5434092/7529156)  are both limited to 100 and this limitation is hardcoded.
So I have more than 100 Implicit conversion warnings and I *don't want* correct them except for conversion from `IntPtr` to `Integer`; as title: how can I find this specific implicit conversion?

I'm also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514724/7529156):

> Can't you temporarily locally do something similar to
>
> `#pragma warning disable`

but it's quite tricky to use in my case

Comment: Based on "Compiler warnings stop to 100", I'm not clear on what you've already tried.  There is a configurable VB compiler warning for implicit conversion (project properties, "Compile" tab, warning configurations); Option Strict On will enable this as a warning, but it can also be configured separately as part of the compiler options.

Comment: Are you saying the compiler is showing you 100 errors in the `Error` tab but you want to see more?

Comment: I edited the question although it was marked as duplicated.
@Craig I aware about warning configurations but I have more than 100 implicit conversion, so I can't see them all even though I set as None all others warnings.
@Bugs Errors or warnings but yes I want see every Implicit conversion from `Integer` to `IntPtr`